# Como mudar a imagem de um botão como JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou fazendo uma clássico jogo da velha em HTML,CSS E JavaScript, porém, quero saber qual comando eu posso usar para poder trocar a imagem de um botão em javascript

Sei que tem alguma coisa a ver com document.getElementById()

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TicTacToe</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   background: #eff2ef;
  }

  #principal{
  }

  #principal td tr{
   background: white;
   margin: 20px;
   border: solid;
   border-color: black;
   padding: 30px;
  }

  #principal td tr label{
   background: white;
  }

 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var fotos = ["images/fundoCinza.jpeg" ," images/fundoX.jpeg " , "images/fundoO.jpeg"];
 </script>
</head>

<body> 
 <div id="tabela" align="center">
  <table id="principal">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>

    <td>     
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
     
    <td>
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>

    <td>     
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
     
    <td>
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
   </tr>


   <tr>
    <td>
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>

    <td>     
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
     
    <td>
     <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
   </tr>   
 </div>

 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Quero que quando eu clique sobre algum desses botões, ele mude pra uma segunda imagem(que no caso vai ser esse fundo cinza com um X na frente

Comment: Você quer que ele automaticamente mude para a próxima imagem da sequência da lista, ou você quer que ele mude para uma foto específica?

Comment: Para uma foto específica

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um pequeno exemplo, no qual ele pega um fundo e o substitui para o "fundoX.jpeg", utilizando a url que esta no seu código.

Ao clicar no elemento button ele pega o seu img e seta a imagem "images/fundoX.jpeg".

```
var elemento = document.querySelector("button");
elemento.onclick = function(){
  this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "images/fundoX.jpeg";
};
```

> Recomendo e altere o `document.querySelector("button")`, porque no meu
>   exemplo ele vai pegar todos os `button` da página, para evitar que ele
>   pegue algum `button` que não seja os que você deseje, crie uma classe
>   para os botões.
>
> Coloquei o código javascript no final dos elementos para que o código
>   javascript seja carregado depois dos elementos renderizados.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>TicTacToe</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style type="text/css">
         body{
          background: #eff2ef;
         }
         #principal{
         
         }
         #principal td tr{
           background: white;
           margin: 20px;
           border: solid;
           border-color: black;
           padding: 30px;
         }
         #principal td tr label{
          background: white;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="tabela" align="center">
         <table id="principal">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
               <td>     
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
               <td>     
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
               <td>     
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
           var fotos = ["images/fundoCinza.jpeg" ,"images/fundoX.jpeg" , "images/fundoO.jpeg"];
           var elemento = document.querySelector("button");
           elemento.onclick = function(){
             this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "images/fundoX.jpeg";
           };
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Crie um evento `onclick` para cada imagem dos botões e altere seu atributo `src` ao ser clicado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TicTacToe</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style type="text/css">
  body{
   background: #eff2ef;
  }

  #principal{
  }

  #principal td tr{
   background: white;
   margin: 20px;
   border: solid;
   border-color: black;
   padding: 30px;
  }

  #principal td tr label{
   background: white;
  }

 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var fotos = ["images/fundoCinza.jpeg" ,"https://uniquephoto2.azureedge.net/resources/uniquephoto/images/products/processed/SVG9050.mediumThumb.b.jpg" , "images/fundoO.jpeg"];

      // aguarda o DOM carregar
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
         // seleciona os botões
         var botoes = document.querySelectorAll("#principal button");
         for(var x=0; x<botoes.length; x++){
            botoes[x].onclick = function(){
               // altera o atributo "src" da imagem do botão clicado
               this.firstElementChild.src = fotos[1];
            }
         }
      });
 </script>
</head>

<body> 
 <div id="tabela" align="center">
  <table id="principal">
   <tr>
    <td>
     <button>
          <img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>

    <td>     
     <button><img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
     
    <td>
     <button><img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>
     <button><img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>

    <td>     
     <button><img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
     
    <td>
     <button><img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
   </tr>


   <tr>
    <td>
     <button><img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>

    <td>     
     <button><img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
     
    <td>
     <button><img src="https://static.webshopapp.com/shops/041466/files/134033882/100x100x2/tenetal-background-272x11m-thunder-gray.jpg" width="100" height="100"></button>
    </td>
   </tr>   
 </div>

 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

O método `getElementById` realmente poderia ser usado. Mas, como o próprio nome diz, ele só irá pegar um objeto através do id do objeto, ou seja, você teria que adicionar um id para cada botão, ou imagem — que aliás não é necessária, conforme a explicação que coloquei abaixo. No entanto, você pode adicionar o atributo `onclick` nas imagens dessa forma:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fotos = ["images/fundoCinza.jpeg" ," images/fundoX.jpeg " , "images/fundoO.jpeg"];
</script>
<button><img src="images/fundoCinza.jpg" width="100" height="100" onclick="this.src = fotos[1]"></button>
```

**Elemento `<img>` desnecessário**

No CSS, existe a propriedade `background-image`, a qual você pode ver mais sobre ela nessa [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-image). Com ela, você pode adicionar uma imagem ao elemento, sem precisar obrigatoriamente da tag `<img>`. E se essa propriedade 
do CSS for utilizada, a abordagem de troca da imagem será um pouco diferente:

```html
<style type="text/css">
    button {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-image: url("images/fundoCinza.jpeg");
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fotos = ["images/fundoCinza.jpeg" ," images/fundoX.jpeg " , "images/fundoO.jpeg"];
</script>
<button onclick="this.style.backgroundImage = `url('${fotos[1]}')`"></button>
```

Espero ter ajudado!